# Could not load file or assembly netstandard when I add migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations, .net-standard

I have an ASP.Net Core 3.0 solution with 2 projects: Web (start project) and Core (class library). I try to create a migration using Package Manager Console:

> add-migration Initial -Project Core -StartupProject Web

and get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Both projects have Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools in references. That's how I create a connection in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connection));
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

and my connectionstring in appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=FinApp;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    }
```

Here's my ApplicationContext.cs:

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Currency> Currencies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Operation> Operations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public ApplicationContext()
    {
    }
}
```

Does anyone have the same issue?

Comment: Does [this StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57779738/error-cannot-load-file-or-assembly-netstandard-version-2-1-0-0) help?

Comment: @panoskarajohn it didn't help, but thank you - I found a link to 'Issues with .NET Standard 2.0 with .NET Framework & NuGet' in answers. I'll try to find out more about the issue.

Comment: @Avitale sorry i sent you the wrong link. Your issue is not transitive dependencies. .NET core & .NET standard issue.  Please provide info about your two projects. Are the two of them .Net Core? Please also see this answer for compatibility of .NET assemblies -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59444690/compatibility-of-dynamically-loaded-assemblies/59445495#59445495

Comment: @panoskarajohn yes, both of them are .Net Core 3.0. So should I use .Net Standard project for my class library instead of .Net Core?

Comment: @Avitale yes. You need to make sure what you install to each project is compatible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support

Comment: @panoskarajohn thank you for help, I used .Net Standard project instead of .Net Core project and it worked! Can you please write your advice as answer for my question (not comment), I'd like to mark it as useful.

Comment: @Avitale no i think my other answer covers this pretty much. Feel free to provide your own answer, If you need to close this. Feel free to upvote this when you can so more people will find this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59444690/compatibility-of-dynamically-loaded-assemblies/59445495#59445495

Answer (score -2):

I think you must define the Context contractor like this:

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
{
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help, I got the same error.