# Visual Studio Windows Forms Designer Error

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-standard-2.1

I’m working on a .NET Standard class library in Visual Studio 2019 that targets both .NET Standard 2.1 and .NET Framework 4.7.2.  I want it to be compatible with WinForms .NET Framework and WPF .NET Core 3.1.  One of its dependencies is Entity Framework 6.4—which only works with .NET Standard 2.1 or .NET Framework 4.7.2—so I can’t down grade to .NET Standard 2.0 in order to be compatible with .NET Framework.  Thus, my class library targets both.

Here’s the .NET Standard library’s .csproj file:

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.1;net472</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup> 

</Project>
```

In the .NET Standard library, I created a class called “NetStandardClass”.  Here’s the code:

```
public class NetStandardClass
{
    private string _member;
    public NetStandardClass(string member)
    {
        _member = member;
    }
}
```

I’ve created a WinForms app that targets  .NET Framework 4.7.2. and references the .NET Standard library.  I created 2 forms:  BaseForm that creates an instance of NetStandardClass and Form1 that derives from BaseForm.

Here’s BaseForm’s code:

```
public partial class BaseForm : Form
{
    public BaseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var netStandardObject = new NetStandardClass("Test");
    }
}
```

Here’s Form1’s code:

```
public partial class Form1 : BaseForm
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Everything compiles and runs with no errors.  Form1 shows with no errors.  I can load BaseForm into the designer with no problems.

However, when I try to load Form1 into the designer, I get the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of it's dependencies.  The system cannot find the file specified.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this the same issue?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57779738/error-cannot-load-file-or-assembly-netstandard-version-2-1-0-0

Comment: I don't think so.  If it was the same, then my app should get the error at run time.  This error is only occurring in the Visual Studio designer.

Comment: Did a little searching and found [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2100).  For at least one person, switching the order of the frameworks targeted in the project definition solved the problem.  That is, does it work if you change `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.1;net472</TargetFrameworks>` into `<TargetFrameworks>net472;netstandard2.1</TargetFrameworks>` in your library where NetStandardClass lives?

Comment: That did it!  If you ask me, this is a Microsoft bug.  According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks), `netstandard2.1` should come first.  However when I put `net472` first, everything worked.  I also verified that it still works with my .NET Core 3.1 libraries & apps.

Comment: Same issue, found 2 projects in the solution with reverted frameworks order. Followed suggestions, but the problem remains. Cleane, rebuild, restart VS

Answer (score 1):

Sean Skelly solved the problem.  In order for everything to work, The .csproj file should look like this:

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net472;netstandard2.1</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I also verified that the .NET Standard and .NET Core apps and libraries are compatible with this .csproj file.

Comment: Unfortunately, while this approach does work, it can't be used by everyone. For instance, if the assembly will be referenced by Xamarin, which is an old style project format, nestandard must appear first as project types that are unaware of the new project system can only 'see' the first target listed. I did file an issue in Developer Community to fix this that could use your votes: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/winforms-designer-uses-assembly-from-wrong-target/1379457